# Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2 - ASP.NET Core Application is missing

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed the Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and updated it to the last version. I choosed the necessary web components in the Visual Studio Installer, tried to execute the `devenv /InstallVSTemplates`, tried to repair Visual Studio and installed .NET Core SDK (x86 and x64).

Nothing of this helped me, I still can't find the ASP.NET Core Application under .NET Core in Visual Studio. How can I solve this problem?

[image: The ASP.NET Core Application is missing]

[image: Components that I choosed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that I found myself: Everything described above was indeed caused by a mistake in the third screen.
I did not find how to solve this problem automatically, I just installed all these `.msi` packages manually. The installer loads them, but for some unknown reason can not install it themselves. To install them manually, you need to go to the directory where Visual Studio is installed, there just look for these packages by name and install them. Then you need to run the installer again and if it shows another error with another package, you need to repeat the procedure with a manual installation. I had to repeat it three times with three different packages. After that, I started the installer once more and it installed the rest.
[image]